# FlutterActivity not working when using cached engine

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-engine

I am trying to open `FlutterActivity` in my existing android application. Before I was creating new flutter engine every time I was opening activity like this:

```
FlutterActivity
   .withNewEngine()
   .build(context)
```

And everything was working fine besides a little lag while opening the activity. To get rid of the lag I wanted to switch to using cached engine. I followed this official tutorial: [LINK](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen?tab=prewarm-engine-kotlin-tab#step-3-optional-use-a-cached-flutterengine)
And ended up with smething like this:

In my Application class:

```
class App : Application() {

    lateinit var flutterEngine: FlutterEngine

    override fun onCreate() {
        ...

        flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)
        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
            DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
        )

        FlutterEngineCache
            .getInstance()
            .put("myEngineId", flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

And later in my application on the button click, in the same place that I was successfully opening  `FlutterActivity`:

```
FlutterActivity
   .withCachedEngine("myEngineId")
   .build(context)
```

So I basically followed the all the instructions but the effect that I get now is after the button click there is even longer lag than before and then there is only black screen being displayed. My flutter screen is not displayed and application is kind of frozen I can't go back or do anything. There is also no error or any useful info in the logs. I have no idea what is going on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any work around?

Answer (score -1):

[To Use cached FlutterEngine](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.html#provideFlutterEngine-android.content.Context-)
In FlutterActivity you must declare **provideFlutterEngine** method.

```
class DemoActivity : FlutterActivity() {

override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? =
    FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(FlutterConstants.ENGINE_ID)

override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "demo-channel")
        .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "demo-method") {
                demoMethod()
                result.success(null)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
}

private fun demoMethod() {
    // Do native code
}

}
```

Comment: Do I really have to create my own implementation of `FlutterActivity`? Can I just the base one? In the tutorial I provided there is no info about that

Comment: @matip

You can check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Reuse-FlutterEngine-across-screens

Comment: It does not work. I still get black screen while using cashed engine